# Auto Complete in JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using ASP.net c#. I have a master page and a content page. Below is the flow.

Content page has script tag

Content page has a update panel and a dropdown list

Update panel contains a grid

Grid has a template column 
template column contains dropdown list

on JQuery load i am calling a method to change the dropdownlist into autocomplete dropdown, this same function is updating the dropdown in grid also.

I have a button in grid header. this is sorting grid rows.

Issue is when i sore the grid rows and due to postback it goes to server and does not update the dropdopwn list in grid.

I doubt that the update panel is not allowing the sciprt tag JQuery load method to call it's plug-ins.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this js function to your content page with your jQuery inside it:

```
function pageLoad()
{
    //put all your jQuery inits and bindings here, this will get called
    //on all partial post backs

}
```

Comment: how to call this function in partial postback case. as the functions in java script gets called on page load or postback. any example pls?

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to rebind the autocomplete plugin to the new content, as the partial-page-refresh replaces the original markup with new markup that has not been bound.

Comment: right. can provide some sample code to dht now i am unable to so? right now, i am unable to call the JQuery on load once the postback executes from grid.

Comment: See @rick schott's answer below.